# MVC View miss aligned after updating EDMX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tfs

I have this partial view in my local source code

[image: picture]

And also same project and using Team Foundation Server (TFS) and after updating my EDMX it becomes like this

[image: this]

I don't why it happens. Anyone know about this issue?

Comment: Is any part of this layout based on values stored in the database?

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider Thanks for the concern. I don't know what happen yesterday but its okay now.

Comment: Could you add the reason in self answer to help more people in this site?